# Tiling Historic Maps using ArcMap

Tags: arcgis-desktop, arcmap, tiles, mosaic, topography

I'm using ArcMap 10.2 on a Windows platform.

I have georeferenced about a dozen USGS topographic raster maps from around 1900.  Each georeferenced map is an now an .mxd file.  To the best of my limited knowledge there are no layers associated with any of these maps.

I would like to tile these into a single map [to which multiple layers would be added] but cannot find a way to do this.

Do I need to start again using a different technique?

Answer (score 1):

Because you don't have that many different mxds, you could open each one and save the georeferenced image as a .lyr file (right-click the layer in the table of contents, then Save As Layer File...).  Put them all in the same folder, then open a blank mxd and it'll be easy to add all of the new .lyr files.

You could also look into creating a Raster Catalog.